# Node.js and Express: How to add script file to ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my first time working with node.js and Express. I have the following project structure:

```
Project/
|-- app/
|   |-- script.js
|
|-- public/
|   |-- css/
|       |-- style.css
|   |
|   |-- resources/
|
|-- views/
|   |-- index.ejs
|
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

Now:

- app.js -> starts the server
- index.ejs -> contains the html code
- style.css -> has the styling
- script.js -> contains the front end functionality of my application

Before creating the server so that my application is run from there, the script file was simply included in the index.html (now the index.ejs) as usual, and everything worked fine. But now just including the script file in the ejs is not enough. In fact, the page just loads on the server but nothing functions.

I have tried adding the following in my script.js file as I found something on here, but it didn't work:

```
const express = require("express");
path = require('path');

const script = express();
script.use(express.static(path.join('../views', 'index')));
```

What do I have to do to link my script.js file with node.js and express, **without having to develop a RESTful application**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `express.static` wrong.

Firstly, you really, really **don't want** to expose your ejs file for others to download. Doing so allows people to see the source code of your server (even if it's only the template) giving them more info to reverse-engineer your app. So remove this:

```
script.use(express.static(path.join('../views', 'index')));
```

Secondly you want people to be able to download your frontend scripts, css and images. To allow this (which is the direct answer to your question) you need to use `express.static`:

```
script.use(express.static(path.join('../app')));
script.use(express.static(path.join('../public')));
```

Once you have set this up you can simply include your frontend script the usual way in your ejs file:

```
<script src="/script.js">
```

The browser will do the rest for you.

---

#### Additional answer:

If you want your script to be served from the `/app` path instead of `/` you can set the path in Express:

```
script.use('/app', express.static(path.join('../app')));
```

Which can then be used as:

```
<script src="/app/script.js">
```

Comment: Note that most people would put their frontend scripts inside the `public` folder to avoid confusion because that's what the `public` folder means - static content

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the heads up on exposing my ejs files. Secondly, I moved the `script.js` to a new folder under public following your recommendation. In my `app.js` file, which starts the server, I have always had the middleware for serving static files in public, so now the `script.js` file is being included! Amazing, thank you so much :) **Also note, I think you meant to write `app.use` not `script.use`.**

Comment: @MariahZammit The name of the variable depends on how you set it up. In your case you used `script = express()` so it would be `script.use()` instead of `app.use()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell express that use are using ejs

```js
// set view engine to ejs
script.set("view engine", "ejs");
// you need to specify views folder too because your script.js is not in // root folder.
app.set('views','../views');
// serve public folder so you can include .css .js in your .ejs file.
app.use("/public", express.static("../public"));

//render you index file
app.use("/", (req,res)=>{
 return res.render("index");
});
```