# How to add use external script file for .ejs pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a beginner at nodeJs and express.
I'm learning over building a small multipage web app project.
But I don't know how to use an external script tag to store all the javascript I'll be using in all my ejs pages.

```
Project/
|-- app/
|   |-- script.js
|
|-- public/
|   |-- css/
|       |-- style.css
| 
|-- views/
|   |-- home.ejs
|
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

Although, I was successful in using a <script> tag in each of the .ejs pages, I'd like to see if it's possible to get all the js in one file, rather than split in multiple.

So far, I tried these but didn't work

1. Placing the js file in an 'app' folder to access it from there, but only works with css

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(\__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(\__dirname + "/app"));
```

2. Using "path.join", but it doesn't work for both the css and js

```
app.use('/app',express.static(path.join('../app')));
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join('../public')));
```

I got no 2. for the answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65303067/20831188, but that was two years ago, so I don't know if it's because I'm using a later version that it doesn't work.

Here's the ejs

```
    <div class="quiz-start" data-quiz='<%= JSON.stringify(savedQuiz) %>'>
        <h1 class="question-display">
            <%= savedQuiz[currentQuizIndex].question %>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="answer-display hidden">
            <%= savedQuiz[currentQuizIndex].answer %>
        </h1>

        <button class="next-btn hidden" onclick="nextQuiz()">Next</button>
        <button class="show-btn" onclick="showAns()">Answer</button>
    </div>
```

Here's the JS

```
let answerShow = document.querySelector(".answer-display")
let nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn")
let showBtn = document.querySelector(".show-btn")

let currentIndex = <%= currentQuizIndex %>;
const savedQuiz = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.quiz-start').dataset.quiz);


function nextQuiz() {
    currentIndex++;
    nextBtn.classList.add("hidden")
    answerShow.classList.add("hidden")
    showBtn.classList.remove("hidden")

    if (currentIndex >= savedQuiz.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    document.querySelector('.question-display').textContent = savedQuiz[currentIndex].question;
    document.querySelector('.answer-display').textContent = savedQuiz[currentIndex].answer;
}

function showAns() {
    answerShow.classList.remove("hidden")
    nextBtn.classList.remove("hidden")
    showBtn.classList.add("hidden")
}
```